# Unknown breakpoint in nlohmann/json framework

Tags: json, xcode, breakpoints, nlohmann-json

Since some time, when I run my app under Xcode with breakpoints enabled, I hit a unknown breakpoint apparently in a system framework called nlohmann::basic_json:

[image]
[image]

I can continue execution without problems, but this is annoying anyway.
Any idea what is the reason for this breakpoint, or even better, how can I avoid it?

Comment: Did you every figure out what this is? Seeing it too using Xcode 11.4.

Comment: Unfortunately no. I had to disable exception breakpoints, which is of course a bad idea.

Comment: I found this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61947265/mysterious-crash-inside-coreanalyticsclient-frameworkconfigurationinit - solution was to re-create the Xcode project from scratch.

Comment: Great! Thanks! I will try it.